# How to create a one to one field to auth_user_user_permissions table in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to add a custom column to `django auth_user__user_permissions` table. But it throws an error...

```
NameError: name 'User_user_permissions' is not defined.
```

Here is the code i have tried.

```
class User_permissions_info(models.Model):
    user_permission = models.OneToOneField(User_user_permissions)
    x = models.ForeignKey(Y,related_name="user_permissions_info")
```

Is there any possible ways to do the same. ?
I know it's possible to create a `one to one` field with `auth_user`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a relationship with any model you like. Your error here is clear, you haven't defined `User_user_permissions`.

Are you actually trying to refer to the `auth.Permission` model? In which case, that's what you need to import and use.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class UserPermissionsInfo(models.Model):
    user_permission = models.OneToOneField(Permission)
```

(note, you should use PEP8-compliant names for your own models).

Comment: actually i want to access the auth_user_user_permission table.

Comment: Fine, but you still haven't defined it: it's fundamental in Python that you must define or import any name you refer to. In this case, import `User` and refer to `User.permissions.through`.